# Dovecot configuration error (Permission denied) - Email for root

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I have setup a local user called postman and logged into it using Thunderbird (IMAP). Following is being shown in the mail error log.

```
Dec 14 23:45:18 ams1 dovecot: lda(root): Fatal: Invalid user settings. Refer to server    log for more information.
Dec 14 23:45:18 ams1 dovecot: lda(root): Error: chdir(/root/) failed: Permission denied (euid=65534(nobody) egid=65534(nogroup) missing +x perm: /root, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0700)
Dec 14 23:45:18 ams1 dovecot: lda(root): Error: chdir(/root) failed: Permission denied
Dec 14 23:45:18 ams1 dovecot: lda(root): Error: user root: Initialization failed:    Initializing mail storage from mail_location setting failed: stat(/root/Maildir) failed:    Permission denied (euid=65534(nobody) egid=65534(nogroup) missing +x perm: /root, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0700)
```

How to solve it and how to exclude root from using mail?

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

Is there a better way of storing emails rather than in /home?

Comment: Are you connecting to the IMAP server using the user 'root'?  Can you screenpaste your thunderbird settings.

Comment: No, I am using a local user called 'postman'. Nothing special in the thunderbird setting. Default settings using STARTTLS

Comment: maybe the user postman doesn't has a home, grep postman /etc/passwd and check the postman exists

Comment: It does exist. Andrzej's answer worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Delivery of email for root (MTA alias)

Standard security recommendation states that email to `root` should be redirected to non privileged user -> In postfix configuration create alias for `root`.

http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html

BTW AFAIR some file system (NFS?) map user `root` to user `nobody`.

Answer (score 1):

Dovecot has configuration options:

```
first_valid_uid         = 26
last_valid_uid          = 0

first_valid_gid         = 6
last_valid_gid          = 0
```

All uids/gids below that values are treated as unacceptable and cause delivery fault. Sure you can easily change first valid uid to zero but, as mentioned above, much better to alias all root and system mail to the some nonprivileged account, preferrably virtual.